# How generating route with parameters using Routing.generate in Symfony2?

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'm trying to generate a path in an Ajax request, but I get the following error:

```
Error: The route "profesor_edit" requires the parameter "id".
```

The code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: Routing.generate('verify_user'),
    data: {name:name},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {

      if(response.data!=null){
          $("#container").load(Routing.generate('user_edit'), { id: response.data }); //"response.data" contains the value returned by the ajax call is an id value
      }
      else{
        $("#container").append("<span >It could not find the id</span>");        
      }   
    } 
  })
```

routing file:

```
user_edit:
     path:     /{id}/edit
     defaults: { _controller: "BackendBundle:User:edit" }
```

I think I will be sending the wrong parameter, but it's the only way I've ever seen. I appreciate your help.

Comment: if you use FOSRoutingBundle, its `Routing.generate('user_edit', resonse.data)` [doku](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#generating-uris)

Comment: Hi @dokumador, I tried your solution and now I get the following error: `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e`. Would you know why that is?

Comment: what is in  `response.data` exactly? it must be the user id.

Comment: Hi @mador, That contains a user id that is returned in the ajax call in the parameter "data" in this way: `return new JsonResponse(array('data' =>$user->getId()), 200);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using FOSJSRoutingBundle, use the following :

```
$("#container").load(Routing.generate('user_edit', { id: response.data }));
```

Comment: Hi @chalasr, thanks for your answer, right now I had come to the same solution